If a person has the ability of attention to details, then they are ...?
It's a bit stronger than careful, it means someone who can analyse/deduce from the details and work out something others can't see. For example, finding out a company is cheating from their financial reports.
Can I say they are attentive to details? A word or a phrase will do.

You are looking for the word fastidious (or one of the other options you can find in any thesaurus).

Then they are attentive is fine.

They are "attentive to detail" (in the singular).  https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sca_esv=5d0811d5ae0715ef&sca_upv=1&sxsrf=ACQVn0-kb6LbRL4YeWsIU321WMhktxhRAg:1713904274544&q=%22attentive+to+detail%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=ivsnbmtz&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN6dn7ltmFAxUFEGIAHaIHAw8Q0pQJegQIbBAB&biw=1205&bih=892&dpr=1.1  Attentive alone connotes (at least in AmE) that their mind doesn't wander when someone else is speaking.

In my neck of the woods, (UK) 'fastidious' can carry a strong element of excessive and supercilious fussiness, as Merriam-Webster notes: (a)
of a person's work, approach, etc. : extremely or excessively careful or detailed, b of a person or trait : characterized by a meticulous, sensitive, or demanding attitude, such as (1) : having high and often capricious standards (2): characterized by extreme or excessive concern about cleanliness or neatness In short, a fastidious person can be 'hard work'.

You will mostly find this concept used in the candidate requirements section of a job description. Usually phrased as something like “Must have good attention to detail”.
It is asking for someone who will notice small errors in a large amount of data, will not be prone to many errors and will not be careless in their work.
If you want what you have described in your question, it would be better to be more specific and ask for insight (or the ability to interpret data in the correct way), perception (for example, the ability to see relevant trends emerging from complex data), and clarity of communication (expressing the important aspects of the data in a way that is easy to understand).
By the way, you can say “they are attentive to details”, but for some reason “they have good attention to details” is more usual in my (BE) experience.

Exactly where I came from.

Someone who has both analytical and deductive skills, can be said to be

perceptive
very good at noticing and understanding things that many people do not notice

From Cambridge Dictionary.

We may consider meticulous:

If you describe someone as meticulous, you mean that they do things very carefully and with great attention to detail.


A common phrase people use to describe someone who pays close attention to details is "detail-oriented."
